# Passing multiple parameters with Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a function in my .aspx page where I collect the first name and last name from the user and would like it to pass back to the server side code(c#). Ajax is being used and runs fine when one parameter is passed, although when a second parameter is passed I receive an error : can someone shed a little light, thanks

ERROR:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 

POST http://ingleParam.aspx/GetCurrentTime 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-.11.1.min.js:4
send jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
ShowCurrentTime SingleParam.aspx:12
onclick
```

.ASPX Code

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "SingleParam.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: {     name: $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").val(), 
                    lastName: $("#<%=txtLastName.ClientID%>").val() },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
```

Server Side Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name, string lastname) {
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The current time is " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with sending json objects to webmethods.  I've had success when I stringify the data being sent across.  Like so:

```
data: JSON.stringify({name: $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").val(), 
                    lastName: $("#<%=txtLastName.ClientID%>").val()}),
```

Give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: With the stringify, I still receive the POST ERROR? When I watch it through the debugger, it makes it through the .aspx code, but never reaches the server side.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, download and run fiddler, it'll give you more insight into the issue.  Also, you can check the event logs for the specific server error that's occurring.  By default you're getting a 500 error which is about as useful as the "check engine" light.